# Appending certain columns in CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm attempting to write a small inventory management program using python, appending and reading an already existing CSV file.

The code lets the user:

1. See current stock
2. Create projects which removes stock
3. Add stock to the file

I've successfully managed to list to the current stock in the CSV file but am having issues trying to allow the user input more stock.

[image: Code]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider excerpting your code and placing it directly in your post, rather than linking to an image. You might find that easier to accomplish if you were to write a function that took an integer argument and generated the output that you have listed after each condition in your while loop.

Comment: Please also read [mcve].